# nginx pcre_compile error when using quantifiers

Tags: nginx, regex

I'm having an issue with aliasing. I want to append up to the first 4 digits of the file as part of the directory. (like '../123456.jpg'=>'../123/123456.jpg' and '../12.png'=>'../12/12.png')

Here is what I have:

```
location ~ ^/i/gallery2/(\d{1,4})(.*)$ {
    alias /home/web/images/gallery/$1/$1$2;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "^/i/gallery2/(\d"
```

Anyone have any ideas how to get this to work? It looks like it has a problem with the "{1,4}" Is there another way to do want I want?

Comment: you should accept @ShaneMadden solution, works perfectly!

Comment: @Stefano Thanks for the reminder. It didn't let me accept it right away and then I forgot about it.

Comment: it happens to me all the time and for various reasons, this is why I tend to remember the others ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It figures you're starting the contents of the location block.  It figures wrong.

Wrap it in quotes:

```
location ~ "^/i/gallery2/(\d{1,4})(.*)$" {
```